# Is $A=\{x\in[-2,2]:x\cos x\ge\frac{1}{2}\sin x \}$ compact?

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

> Is $A=\{x\in[-2,2]:x\cos x\ge\frac{1}{2}\sin x \}$ compact?

Clearly, $A$ is bounded, so if I want to show that $A$ is compact, then I need to show that $A$ is closed. For any sequence $(a_n)$ in $A$ and $a_n\to a$, I need to show that $a\in A$. But I think I can not check all such sequence, so I guess $A$ is not compact and it suffices to find a sequence $(a_n)$ in $A$ and $a_n\to a$ but $a\notin A$. Hope someone could give me some hints.

Comment: **HINT** $f(x)=x\cos x-\frac{1}{2}\sin x$ is continuous, so if $f(a_n)\ge 0$ and $a_n\to a$.....

Comment: Then $f(a)\ge 0$

Comment: So, you are done.

Comment: oh, so $A$ is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ is the intersection of the inverse image of the closed set $[0,+\infty)$ by the  *continuous* function $f(x)=x\cos x-\frac 12\sin x\,$ with the closed interval $[-2,2]$, so it is closed.